# MATCH AGAINST in MySQL don't work

Tags: mysql, sorting, match, against

I have a problem with FULLTEXT search in MySql. 
I create query:

```
SELECT searchTag, MATCH (searchTag) AGAINST ('after party') as score FROM post WHERE MATCH (searchTag) AGAINST ('after party') ORDER BY score DESC
```

Its result:

```
 1. we,like,to,party 3.6987853050231934 
 2. f,w,g,party 3.6987853050231934
 3. after,party,tooka 3.657205581665039
```

Why number `3` have `lower` score if it have `two words` searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`after` is a stop word.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) It is ignored by a FULLTEXT `MATCH` query.

Basically, the word "after" is so common in the English language that including it in a query is semantically meaningless.

Think of it this way: imagine a query against the word "a". There are so many sentences which use the word "a", that a match against them really won't provide you with anything useful.

In this post, all of the sentences reference the word "a".